# How does the partial derivative of a tensor of rank $n$ creates a tensor of rank $n+1$? (cartesian coordinates)

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, differentiation

The partial derivative of a tensor of rank $n$, $T_{...i}$, with respect to $x^j$ can be expressed using the transformation rule:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}T'_{...i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\sum_{...k}...\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^i}T_{...k}
\end{equation}

Since the derivative is linear:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}T'_{...i}=\sum\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(...\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^i}T_{...k}) 
\end{equation}

If I'm correct, applying the product rule and knowing that $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}=\delta^i_j$ yields:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}T'_{...i}=\sum_{...k}...\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^i}\frac{\partial T_{...k}}{\partial x^j}
\end{equation}

I'm having trouble interpreting the result. I believe it's not even correct. What's the $\frac{\partial T_{...k}}{\partial x^j}$ factor?

Comment: You mean the *covariant* derivative.

Comment: First off, do you understand _why_ the derivative increases the rank? Steve Girvin once said to me "Never do a calculation unless you already know the answer." So I would recommend convincing yourself that the rank should go up before getting lost in the clerical details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to proceed is:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} T'_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \left(\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial x'^i}T_{s}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \left(\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial x'^i}\right)T_{s}+\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial x'^i}\frac{\partial T_{s}}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial x'^q}{\partial x^j} \,\frac{\partial^2 x^s}{\partial x'^i \partial x'^q}\,T_{s}+\frac{\partial x^s}{\partial x'^i}\frac{\partial T_{s}}{\partial x^j}$

I don't think you get cancellation there. Casing point. Polar and Cartesian coordinates in 2d:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\,\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\,\cos\phi=-\sin\phi\neq0$

Comment: I agree, although, generally, I woudln't commute the partial derivatives for $x^{i'}$ and $x^{q'}$.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated,

\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{j} }
\left( \frac{ \partial x^{k} }{ \partial x^{i'} } \right)
=
\frac{ \partial x^{j'} }{ \partial x^{j} }
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\left( \frac{ \partial x^{k} }{ \partial x^{i'} } \right)
\neq
\delta^{i}_{j}
\end{equation}

Consider a 1° order tensor. Usually we refer to the transformation rule of the derivative wrt the coordinates in which the tensor is expressed on. By that, I mean
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial T^{i}(x) }{ \partial x^{j} }
\to 
\frac{ \partial T^{i'}(x') }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\end{equation}
rather than
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial T^{i}(x) }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\end{equation}

Note that not even the first one yields a tensorial transformation.
\begin{align}
\frac{ \partial T^{i'}(x') }{ \partial x^{j'} }
&=
\frac{ \partial x^{j} }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{j} }
\left( T^{i'}(x') \right)
\\
&=
\frac{ \partial x^{j} }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x^{j} }
\left(
\frac{ \partial x^{i'} }{ \partial x^{i} }
T^{i}(x)
\right)
\\
&=
\frac{ \partial x^{j} }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\left[
\frac{ \partial^{2} x^{i'} }{ \partial x^{j} \partial x^{i} }
T^{i}(x)
+
\frac{ \partial x^{i'} }{ \partial x^{i} }
\frac{ \partial T^{i}(x) }{ \partial x^{j} }
\right]
\\
\frac{ \partial T^{i'}(x') }{ \partial x^{j'} }
&=
\underbrace{
\frac{ \partial x^{j} }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\frac{ \partial x^{i'} }{ \partial x^{i} }
\frac{ \partial T^{i}(x) }{ \partial x^{j} }
}_{\text{cov}}
+
\underbrace{
\frac{ \partial x^{j} }{ \partial x^{j'} }
\frac{ \partial^{2} x^{i'} }{ \partial x^{j} \partial x^{i} }
T^{i}(x)
}_{\text{non cov.}}
\end{align}

What I mean by "covariant" and "non covariant" is simply that the 1° term is how you'd expect a 2° order tensor to transform. A covariant derivative (a derivative that transforms as a tensor) is defined by adding a term that cancells the spurious 2° term.